# Higher order polynomial Kalman filter terms

Tags: kalman-filter, transition-matrix

This is a snapshot from the book "Fundamentals of Kalman Filtering: A Practical Approach
Book by Paul Zarchan."

For a system: $\dot{x} = Fx + Qu + w$, the table 4.2 lists the discrete fundamental matrix $\Phi_k = \Phi (T_s)$ where $\Phi = e^{Ft}$, and $Q_k = \int_0^{T_s}\Phi(\tau) Q \Phi^T(\tau) d\tau$ where $T_s$ is the sampling time of the measurements.
[image]

Are there any quick methods to compute these terms for any given $F$? Assuming that $Q = \mathbf{0}$. I'm hoping there are resources that may already have these terms in a different form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are techniques to do this. One method is the numerical technique developed by C.F Van Loan in [this](http://www.olemartin.no/artikler/vanloan.pdf) paper and further explained in Section 3.9 of [this](https://www.wiley.com/en-in/Introduction+to+Random+Signals+and+Applied+Kalman+Filtering+with+Matlab+Exercises,+4th+Edition-p-9780470609699) book. A brief description of the technique is as follows:

Suppose we are given a continuous time system $\dot{x} = Fx + Qu$, where $x$ is the $ n \times 1$ state vector and $u$ is the driving white noise vector with power spectral density matrix $W$.

1) First, compute the following $2n \times 2n$ matrix

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} -F & QWQ^T \\ 0 & F^T \end{bmatrix} \Delta t $

$\Delta t $ is the sampling time of the system.

2) Next compute the matrix exponential of A. MATLAB has a built-in function `expm(A)`

$M = e^A = \begin{bmatrix} B_{11} & B_{12} \\ B_{21} & B_{22} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cdot \cdot \cdot & \Phi_k^{-1}Q_k \\ 0 & \Phi_k^T \end{bmatrix} $

3) According to this technique, the lower right partition of $M$ is the transpose of the state transition matrix. Thus,

$\Phi_k = B_{22}^T$

4) The discrete process noise matrix is obtained as:

$Q_k = \Phi_k B_{12}$

Hope this helps.